# JFace WizardSelectionPage and IWizardNode

Tags: java, dialog, jface, wizard

How one can combine JFace wizards using WizardSelectionPage and IWizardNode ?

Have anyone tried this before ? I didn't find any example in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example http://www.mikero.nl/java/how-to-use-wizardselectionpage/.

It shows how to create a `WizardSelectionPage` which displays a viewer containing a list of `IWizardNodes`. When an item is selected, the selected node is passed to `setSelectedNode' which initialises the nested wizard. Pressing`Next` opens the first page of the nested wizard.

Comment: FWIW: The link is dead (sorry), but a snippet with comments is still available at https://gist.github.com/mrombout/6019148#file-wizardselectionpagesnipercomments-java.